# I am new to Java EE so where do I start?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, applet

I already have basic knowledge of HTML, CSS, JS, JSP, Servlet, applet. Before I go to the industry I need to be good with Java EE. So Please help me. I will really appreciate can someone give me a clear path from begin to end. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you know about best books to refer? Also if you know about best video resources can you comment here? Thanks!

Comment: Try with a framework like Spring DAO, hibernate